# Get information from Facebook with Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, jsoup

My question is, can we retrieve data from post of a Facebook group to an app and then use it?
I've heard about [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), to get information from any website, but will it work in Facebook?

Comment: If you did try to use Jsoup, you'd have to authentic and pretend to be logged in to get any useful information. Alternatively, you need a Facebook API key and use that to get information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Jsoup to scrape Facebook for group data.  They have an API that you can can use:

[Facebook Graph API > Group Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/group/feed)

Comment: Links are nice, but this could be improved with an example

Comment: It would be hard to give an example of how to use an API. That seems like a fairly broad topic. For a developer asking how to retrieve data, giving them a reference API is more than enough and not anything that can be taught in one answer.